# OCR in pytorch/keras with LPRNet and CTCLoss doesn't converge

Tags: keras, pytorch, ocr, lpr, ctc

I implemented LPRNet from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.10447) in keras and then in pytorch. For pytorch was used this [code](https://github.com/xuexingyu24/License_Plate_Detection_Pytorch/blob/master/LPRNet/model/LPRNET.py) as example. It didn't converge in any version. Loss starts at 30 and goes to 27 even after 150000 epochs. In pytorch version I am not using validation, for faster training.

what I tried:

- initialized conv2d weights with xavier_uniform_, xavier_normal and all the others I found in torch.nn.init
- used another dataset with 50 clear images used by other guys for their rcnn ocr model
- tried sgd instead of adam

full colab with pytorch is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gF-KmV4ZBc7Gwpe08Y2uQO2gunE-fyT6?usp=sharing) and my dataset is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1c88T-bcepkl-VAiWTDFjGZ6UlQvoNye0?usp=sharing)

In keras I once succeded to overfit the model over training set. My training set has only 50 images but I apply random effect for not overfitting. In their paper, authors didn't specify how large dataset they used. May be the problem is in the model implementation ? Also, original paper contained spatial transformer network which I didn't use because they told it's optional, but can it's absence be an issue ?

```
class Softmax(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        #se aplica pt torch.Size([1, 30, 1, 74])
        return torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(x, 3)

class Reshape(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        # se aplica pt torch.Size([1, 30, 1, 74])
        #pentru CTCloss
        #trebuie sa fie (T,N,C) , where T=input length, N=batch size, C=number of classes
        x = x.permute(3, 0, 1, 2)
        return x.view(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2])

def init_weights(m):
    if type(m) == nn.Conv2d:
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(m.weight)
        #m.bias.data.fill_(0.01)

class small_basic_block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ch_in, ch_out):
        super().__init__()
        self.block = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(ch_in, ch_out//4, kernel_size=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(ch_out//4, ch_out//4, kernel_size=(3,1), padding=(1,0)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(ch_out//4, ch_out//4, kernel_size=(1,3), padding=(0,1)),
            nn.Conv2d(ch_out//4, ch_out, kernel_size=1)
        )
        self.block.apply(init_weights)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.block(x)

class LPRNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, class_num):
        super().__init__()
        self.lprnet = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=1),
            small_basic_block(ch_in=64, ch_out=128),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(1, 3, 3), stride=(2, 2, 1)),
            small_basic_block(ch_in=64, ch_out=256),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            small_basic_block(ch_in=256, ch_out=256),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(1,3,3), stride=(4,2,1)),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(4,1), stride=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Conv2d(256, class_num, kernel_size=(1,13), stride=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=class_num),
            nn.ReLU(), # torch.Size([1, 30, 1, 74])
            Softmax(),
            Reshape()
        )
        self.lprnet.apply(init_weights)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.lprnet(x)

ctc_loss = nn.CTCLoss(blank=alphabet.index('$'))

model = LPRNet(len(alphabet)+1)
model.to(dev)
opt = optim.Adam(model.parameters())
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(opt, step_size=100000, gamma=0.1)

def train(epochs):
    for i in range(epochs):
        X_data, Y_data, X_data_len, Y_data_len = train_set.next_batch()
        X_data = model(X_data)
        loss = ctc_loss(X_data, Y_data, X_data_len, Y_data_len)
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()
        opt.zero_grad()
        scheduler.step()
```

Comment: It has to do with the dataset, are you using any standard dataset to train?

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi, I used another dataset which worked for someone. Actual dataset is made by me, these are 24x94 license plates cut from images with cars.

Comment: Could be your dataset is too hard for CTC, there is no way to validate that. I would suggest try with a standard benchmark dataset first.